# I need detailed direction to use osm2po or osm2pgrouting

Tags: osm2po, osm2pgrouting

I am a very beginner with osm2po and osm2pgrouting.
I read lots of materials (e.g., http://anitagraser.com/2011/12/15/an-osm2po-quickstart/) regarding these two software, but I can't even start how to use it.
I don't know how to use jar files and where I need to type command lines...

Should I install the java program or that can be possible only in QGIS?

Can someone provide me very detailed explanation using one of these two software?
If there is a screenshot, that should be wonderful!
I have no background about programming about java.

Comment: I'm not sure what better resources / more detailed explanation is available beyond the link you provided.  This should be fairly simple stuff.  If you have no experience with programming, java, using the command line, using postgreSQL, using postGIS, etc....  then this is going to be very hard, even if somebody walked you through it step by step.  First of all, all this stuff is almost entirely independent of QGIS.  Though it can be consumed in QGIS, you will be setting this stuff up with regular commandline functions to interact with a postgreSQL database, then connecting to that with QGIS.

Comment: So when the tutorial (in the link you mentioned) tells you to download the jars and then run a command, you do exactly that and then run the command in commandline (cmd), altering the paths to wherever your jar files actually are.

Comment: Would a live CD / USB key be an option for you?

Comment: Anything can help me out would be welcome for me! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments, expecting a complete tutorial for someone with little computer admin experience is unrealistic, and unlikely to really help you. Sorry if that isn't what you wanted to hear.

I'd suggest two options, depending on your cash / time trade-off, and what you are actually trying to achieve:

- Pay someone to do this for you. In the end, the money it will cost could be offset by getting it done sooner, and the money you can make doing something that you have skills and experience in.
- Start with a live CD or USB key that has it already working, and experiment with that. Perhaps http://live.osgeo.org/en/index.html may be an option (I didn't actually test for those two applications, but it will provide a sound learning environment). When you have more experience, you can step up to doing custom installations.